# How can I treat several views as one in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want set visibility of several views programmatically. Is there some way to treat them as one single view(or viewgroup)?

Comment: Yes. Why not put them in a ViewGroup yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at a new feature in `ConstraintLayout` "group". By grouping views in `ConstraintLayout` using this feature you can set their visibility as one. See this [Medium Post](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/whats-new-in-constraint-layout-1-1-x-f0bdd4dbdfb3#016b).

> Group
>
> Groups, like the Guidelines, are widgets with size 0. But Group helps to apply some action to a set of widgets. The most common case, is to control a visibility of a collection of widgets.

Comment: Note: requires ConstraintLayout 1.1.0-beta